# How to send an array of files using FormData?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

In the backend in laravel I have a field called "file_ticket" and I need to send an array that contains files sent through an input file, I use vue js in the frontend.
How can I send this array to my backend? When I try to send only the array, the request returns something like "object file"

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d48Ok.jpg)

```
onChange(e) {
  let getFiles = [...this.$refs.file.files]
  
  if(!getFiles) return
  ([...getFiles]).forEach(f => {
    this.filelist.push(f)
  })      
},


saveTicket(event){
  event.preventDefault()      
               
  let frmData =  new FormData()
  frmData.append('subject', this.newTicket.subject) 
  frmData.append('service', this.newTicket.service) 
  frmData.append('description', this.newTicket.description)       
  frmData.append('file_ticket', this.filelist)       
  frmData.append('client_id', this.idUser) 


  const url = `ticket/new_ticket`

  axios.post(url, frmData).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
```

Comment: Use JSON. On the server side use `json_decode`. On the client use `JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]);`, where [1, 2, 3] is your array.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE I don't think you can do that. I'm pretty sure you have to use `FormData()`

Comment: I'm saying, send the stringified JSON in the form data

Comment: If I use JSON.stringy(), send an array with empty objects

Answer (score 5):

Just append all the files in `filelist` to formdata using the same key, it will send an array of files.

```js
this.filelist.forEach((file) => {
    frmData.append('file_ticket', file);
});
```

Comment: Not woking with single file.. file_ticket is not array for single file...  this worked only for multiple files

Comment: That's a different issue, a problem in your backend implementation where you receive the multipart formdata. This is a front-end question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending your files to another array as done in the question append directly but with added square brackets.

Instead of using this:

```js
this.filelist.push(f)
```

just append the file to the form data object like this:

```
 frmData.append('file_ticket[]', file);
```

In your Laravel controller just use this code to take your files
(I assume you're using POST and you're passing the Request object as your parameter to your controller function)

```php
if ($request->hasFile('file_ticket')) {
   $file_tickets = $request->file('file_ticket');
   foreach ($file_tickets as $index => $file_ticket) {
      //The rest of your code goes here
   }
}
```

The `hasFile` function checks if your request has that file ticket and the `$request->file` is used to get the array of files.